# String identifier within another string

Tags: c, string

Is it possible to have a string identifier inside another string identifier, and print the entire thing? For example:

```
int main()
{
    char *str1 = "%s says:";
    char *name = "John";
    printf("%s\n", str1, name);
    return(0);
}
```

My expected output would be `John says:`. How would I printf or sprintf something like this?

Comment: Have you tried it? Wouldn't `printf(str1, name);` make more sense?

Comment: ... and notice that `printf("%s\n", str1, name);` has one format specifier, but two arguments. the second will be ignored.

Comment: What is a "string identifier"?

Comment: `#define STR1 "%s says:"
char *name = "John";
printf(STR1 "\n" , name);`

Answer (score 2):

No, `printf` cannot be made to work that way. You would have to do this in two separate stages:

```
const char *fmt = "%s says: ";
char result1[SIZE];             // where SIZE is large enough to hold the result
sprintf( result, fmt, "John" ); // result now contains "John says: "
printf( "%s\n", result );       // writes "John says: " to standard output
```

I've had to do variations on this a number of times, where I needed to build format strings on the fly.  That's about as easy as it gets.

Comment: Funny how it just makes more sense when you call the variable holding the *format string* `fmt`...

Answer (score 1):

THINK about what printf() is doing.

printf() sees the "%s" and interprets it as, print the indicated string.  The indicated string just happens to contain the characters "%s": how is printf() to know that?  It doesn't automatically rescan and rescan.

How about having a loop.  Gather up the characters and sprintf() them into a buffer.  Each time around, if there's still another '%' in the string, reapply sprintf().  When you're done, just dump out the string literally with puts().

Comment: Well, it very well could recursively interpret the strings. Reason `printf` does not work like this is not because it is not possible, but it is a very bad idea fro security reasons (what if a user-supplied string is to be printed? - this is the reason one always should use a well known format string) and complexity. That function already is one of the largest in the standard library (along with the `scanf` family).